# App Store Mac OS Monterey 12.5 downloads 12.4

Tags: monterey

Checking the Mac App Store for Monterey I can see that the version is listed as 12.5. However, upon downloading and doing a clean install the resulting version is 12.4.

Anybody else experiencing this?
Is 12.5 just a delta download via software update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it was a CDN issue. It was downloading installer version 17.4.01, it is now 17.5.01

Answer (score 2):

If you already have 12.4 installed, you can upgrade to 12.5

- in **System Preferences** -> **Software Update**
- by running `sudo softwareupdate --install --os-only` in Terminal

Both options will download the update, log out all users and restart the system to install the update.

**Note**: User logout may get stopped by running applications (e.g. if there are unsaved changes). So make sure to save your work before.